# pytest-flask -- can not access application's endpoints from test client function

Tags: python, flask

Edit:

After moving stuff around and renaming things, I'm revising this post to reflect my current issue.

I'm unable to access the endpoints in the files inside my `views` folder. I thought importing them explicitly in `test_example.py` or having them already imported in `__init__.py` would do the trick.

Here's the error when running `pytest`:

```
    rv = self._partial_build(endpoint, values, method, append_unknown)
    if rv is None:
>       raise BuildError(endpoint, values, method, self)
E       werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint '/api/create_booth'. Did you mean 'static' instead?
```

Also, I tried substituting `url_for('some_endpoint')` with `url_for('some_endpoint', _external=True)` -- had no effect.

Here's my directory structure and the simplified contents of the relevant files:

**directory structure**

```
server/
    my_app/
        __init__.py
        views/
            __init__.py
            some_views.py
    test/
        __init__.py
        conftest.py
        test_example.py
```

**__init__.py:**

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    return app

app = create_app()
from views.some_view import *    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**conftest.py**

```
import pytest
from my_app import create_app

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app()
    return app
```

**test_example.py**

```
from flask import url_for
from my_app.views.some_views import some_endpoint

def test_some_endpoint(client):
    assert client.post(url_for('some_endpoint'),
           data=json.dumps(dict(some_attr='some_value')),
           content_type='application/json').status_code == 200
```

**some_views.py**

```
from my_app import app

@app.route('/api/some_endpoint/', methods=['POST'])
def some_endpoint():
    return "success"
```

I'm running `pytest-flask-0.10.0`, `Python 3.4.3`, and `Flask 0.12.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should really consider reorganizing your app structure. The way you are doing it will lead to circular imports which is probably why you have your views import after your app creation. I would suggest moving your app factory into its own file since you will reuse it in your tests.

## my_app/factory.py

```
def create_app():
    # init extensions
    # init blueprints
    return app
```

Then while your app is small simply keep the views in `app.py` As your app gets larger consider implementing the `blueprint` design pattern -> [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/blueprints/)

## my_app/app.py

```
from factory import create_app

app = create_app()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'hello'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

In your tests

## test_example.py

```
from factory import create_app

@py.fixture
def client():
    return create_app().test_client()

def test_route(client):
    response = client.get('/')
    assert response.json() == 'hello', 'Route should return "hello"'
```

Miguel Grinberg has a really great [blog](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/category/Flask) on Flask he's the author of [Flask Web Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1449372627) which is an excellent resource. Looks like he is in the process of rewriting his tutorial on flask.

## Blueprints example

## my_app/factory.py

```
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    from main import main
    app.register_blueprint(main)

    return app
```

## my_app/main.py

```
from flask import Blueprint

main = Blueprint('main', __name__)

@main.route('/')
def index():
    return "hello"
```

## my_app/app.py

```
from factory import create_app

app = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Hope that helps